# grub recovery in rescue mode

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu side by side to Windows 7 on my PC. I used the same install disk for my two PCs. On my 1st PC everything is working good! Second PC I sometimes get the boot error:

`no such device: (numbers and letters) entering rescue mode grub rescue> ....`

From here I've tried everything I've seen on the internet. When I run

```
ls (hd0) (hd0msdos1)
```

and

```
(hd0msdos2)  cmdpath=hd0 prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub root=hd0
```

I booted from Ubuntu disk again, ran the try Ubuntu, opened a terminal looked for partitions found linux on `dev/sdb5`.

Like I said I tried everything and i still get the grub rescue when it boots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this problem before.  Maybe you can try to boot with the live CD on the PC that causes problem and follow the guide to Boot-Repair here : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It worked for me on my Asus Laptop.

Let me know if it works for you !

Comment: Glad I could help!